# How to configure express server for handling REST endpoints as well as socket.io connections

Tags: rest, express, socket.io

How do I implement a socket.io connection on a server which is also handling RESTful endpoints 
I mean for one specific address of my app, the users should be able to do real time communications like so

```
my-app.com/feeds --> this should be capable of real time messaging
```

So my express server is set up like this

```
imports here

app.use('/api/users' require('./users'))
app.use('/api/items' require('./items'))

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('running'))
```

now how do I use WebSockets using socket.io to manage incoming connections? I want only 
my-app.com/feeds to support real time communication?

should I use `io.use()` like `app.use()` ?

What is the approach I should take so that I can structure all the socket.io connections in a separate file and use because rest is stateless and socket.io is stateful?

can I use something like `io.use('/api/feeds' do something here)` is this approach proper?

Please guide me

Comment: What if you used `app.get("/api/feeds", (req, res))` then establish a connection in the callback, easily disconnect when the url changes

Comment: @Ameer so How do I proceed?